# Creating a grid of images that connect with each other

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to make a grid of images that connect nicely with each other.

Here is my grid:
http://www.yannickluijten.be/test2

Not every image has the same height so this is the problem:
I want the 4th image (gray) to appear below the first image (green) and I don't want to work with 3 columns. How can I do this?

```
.img1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: green;
}

.img2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}

.img3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}

.img4 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    background: gray;
}
```

Comment: Once that blue box get floated there like that, the space below the green box down to the edge of the blue box becomes unavailable (can't be filled, unless you absolutely position something there). Have you considered using a three-column layout rather than floating things?

Comment: Maybe something like this http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/? (Works only in modern browsers)

Comment: what I'm really trying to do is loading images automatically from my tumblr account and putting them into a grid like that. So the three-column layout isn't possible because I only have a javascript link that I have to implement (that's already working, link updated). How can I do this with position absolute?

Comment: this is what I'm trying to reach: http://socialsketch.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS floats, there's no way to control when variable-height floated elements should "wrap around" to the left edge, without causing unwanted vertical spacing to appear between some of them.

A mosaic plug-in like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html) is geared for this sort of thing. Not sure if it lets you control which photo appears in which column, but it may work adequately.

You could use [CSS columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), but it offers limited control over which photo should appear in which column, and it doesn't work in IE9 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
.img4 {
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
float: left;
background: gray;
clear: both;
}
```

fourth image comes in first row but not exactly under the first image.